# Filter in angular-grid is showing irrelevant filters once filtering data using one column - Angular Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-grid

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#gsc.tab=0

I am referring this link but didn't get any option to implement filter properly.

I referred **Built In Filters Example** but in angular-grid.js @version v1.12.4 this functionality doesn't works properly.

I am trying to filter my grid in same way in example :
If United States Filter is applied for Country then in Atlete column I shouldn't get an option of other country's player.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to show your code, what you are trying to filter ?

Comment: I am trying to filter rows on the basis of header : jsfiddle link

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/5J1JKrps3SiPzRQHfEaX?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @Robus for replying. I used the version 2.3.5 of ag-grid which resolved my filter question.